# Uploading item in Amazon s3 bucket from React Native with user's info

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am uploading an image on AWS S3 using React Native with AWS amplify for mobile app development. Many users use my app.

1. I want that whenever any user uploads the image on S3 through the mobile app, I want to get user's ID **also** along with that image. So that later I can recognise the images on S3 that which image belongs to which user. How can I achieve this?
2. I am using AWS Auth Cognito for user registration/ Sign-In. I came to know that whenever a user is registered in AWS cognito (for the first time), the user gets a unique ID in the pool. Can I use this user ID to be passed alongwith image whenever user uploads image?

Basically I want to have some form of functionality so that I can track back to the user who uploaded the image on S3. This is because after the image is uploaded on S3, I later want to process this image and send the result back **ONLY** to the user of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in S3 in structure similar to the one below:

```
users/
   123userId/
       image1.jpeg
       image2.jpeg
   anotherUserId456/
       image1.png
       image2.png
```

Then, if you need all files from given user, you can use ListObjects API in S3 lambda - [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property)

```
// for lambda function
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const objects = await s3.listObjectsV2({
      Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      Delimiter: 'STRING_VALUE',
      EncodingType: url,
      ExpectedBucketOwner: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Marker: 'STRING_VALUE',
      MaxKeys: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
      Prefix: 'STRING_VALUE',
      RequestPayer: requester
    }).promise()

objects.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item
)});
```

Or if you are using S3 Lambda trigger, you can parse userId from "key" / filename in received event in S3 lambda (in case you used structure above).

```
 {
          "key": "public/users/e1e0858f-2ea1-90f892b68e0c/item.jpg",
          "size": 269582,
          "eTag": "db8aafcca5786b62966073f59152de9d",
          "sequencer": "006068DC0B344DA9E9"
 }
```

Another option is to write "userId" into metadata of the file that will be uploaded to S3.
You can pass "sub" property from Cognito's currently logged user, so in S3 Lambda trigger function you will get the userId from metadata.

```
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";

const user = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
const userId = user.attributes.sub;
return userId;



// use userId from Cognito and put in into custom metadata
import {Storage} from "aws-amplify";

const userId = "userIdHere"
const filename = "filename" // or use uuid()
const ref = `public/users/@{userId}/${filename}`

const response = await Storage.put(ref, blob, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        metadata: {userId: userId},
      });
```

AWS Amplify can do all above automatically (create folder structures, etc.), if you do not need any special structure how files are stored = [docs here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js).
You only need to configure Storage ('globally' or per action) with "level" property.

```
Storage.configure({ level: 'private' });
await Storage.put(ref, blob, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        metadata: {userId: userId},
      });


//or set up level only for given action
const ref= "userCollection"
await Storage.put(ref, blob, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        metadata: {userId: userId},
        level: "private"
      });
```

So, for example, if you use level "private", file "124.jpeg" will be stored in S3 at
"private/us-east-1:6419087f-d13e-4581-b72e-7a7b32d7c7c1/userCollection/124.jpeg"

However, as you can see, "us-east-1:6419087f-d13e-4581-b72e-7a7b32d7c7c1" looks different than the "sub" in Cognito ("sub" property does not contain regions).

The related [discussion is here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1847), also with few workarounds, but basically you need to decide how you will manage user identification in your project on your own (if you use "sub" everywhere as userId, or you will go with another ID - I think it is called identityID and consider that as userId).

PS: If you are using React Native, I guess you will go with Push Notification for sending updates from backend - if that is the case, I was doing something similar ("moderation control") - so I added another Lambda function, Cognito's Post-Confirmation Lambda, that creates user in DynamoDB with ID of Cognitos's "sub" property.
Then user can save token from mobile device needed for push notifications, so when the AWS Rekognition finished detection on the image that user uploaded, I queried DynamoDB and used SNS to send the notification to the end user.